# MKPinAnnotationView Callout button should pass custom object to Details ViewController

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview, callouts

I have an annotation class that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. The class has an init method which sets coordinates, title, and subtitle.

I create an array of these annotations and add them to a MKMapView the normal way by using `addAnnotations:annotationArray`.

Then in the MKMapViewDelegage method `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` I create a MKPinAnnotationView with a custom pin color, animatesDrop, canShowCallout. The callout has a UIButton of type `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`.

When I run the application and click on a pin on the map I get the expected results which is the callout with title, subtitle, and the detailDisclosure button.

The thing I'm trying to figure out is how to pass data to a details page (`[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsController animated:YES];`) when the user clicks the detail disclosure button. I tried to modify my annotations class by adding an additional parameter to the init method however I cannot access that parameter in the `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control` method. It seems I can only access title and subtitle from there by doing something like this `[view.annotation title]`.

I'm not sure what to do here, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this either...

Again. I want to pass an object to a detail view controller. The object would contain various data that would be used on the details page...

PS - I'm using Xcode 4.2 w/ ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, the annotation reference is the exact annotation object you created and added but the reference is typed generically as `id<MKAnnotation>`.

To access the custom properties in your annotation class, you can first cast it:

```
YourAnnotationClass *myAnn = (YourAnnotationClass *)view.annotation;

//now you can explicitly reference your custom properties...
NSLog(@"myAnn.customProp = %@", myAnn.customProp);
```

Make sure the "customProp" is defined as a property in your annotation class.

Comment: Yeah - but be SURE to check the class type of `myAnn` first. If the user taps the "Current Location" annotation you will also get this message - and if you're assuming it's one of your classes, it will break with a method not implemented exception.

Comment: Thanks Anna, this worked beautifully! Also thanks to you Steve for pointing the current location issue out. I've implemented some additional code to prevent this error `if ([myMapAnnotation isKindOfClass:[MyMapAnnotation class]])`